# Linux live distro including OpenShot and/or Kdenlive

Tags: video-editing, linux-distribution

Which Linux live distro coming with OpenShot and/or Kdenlive is there and would you suggest me to try?
I need to very occasionally use them and I don't want to install them by the moment.

Thanks in advance for your advices.

Comment: By taking a look [here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/6-linux-distros-designed-artists-musicians-editors/), I know that [Ubuntu Studio](http://ubuntustudio.org), [APODIO](http://apodio.org/), [io GNU/Linux](http://io.gnu.linux.free.fr) and [AV Linux](http://www.bandshed.net/avlinux/) (the first two based on Ubuntu the last two on Debian) should provide a live distro including one or both of them (while [KXStudio](http://kxstudio.linuxaudio.org/) and [AudioPhile Linux](https://www.ap-linux.com/download/) are more focused on audio/music instead)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you actually listed the majority of the distros shipping `OpenShot` + `Kdenlive`. I'm afraid there might be performance issues on live systems when it comes to video processing and encoding. To overcome these sorts of problem you probably might want to use a well-supported distro with a good drivers database, such as [Ubuntu Studio 17.04](http://ubuntustudio.org/), which includes both OpenShot and Kdenlive out of the box:

[image]

Keep in mind though that right now Ubuntu as a project undergoes serious changes, shifting its focus from the desktop distros to the cloud-based/server-side solutions, which means that Ubuntu Studio might not be the best Linux-based solution for the artists in the future.

Comment: Yeah, I'm aware that I may face performance issues on live systems... especially dealing with video-editing! Anyway I do it rarely, as I told, and I deal with very short videos (less than a minute) for the moment. I accept your as the answer: I tried Ubuntu Studio, it comes with both OpenShot and Kdenlive and I think it is a good solution for me (I'd have been curious to try even Shotcut while I was at it but it's not there... You can't always have it all ;-D )

Comment: Can you please give more information about your last words: "Keep in mind though that right now Ubuntu as a project undergoes serious changes, shifting its focus from the desktop distros to the cloud-based/server-side solutions, which means that Ubuntu Studio might not be the best Linux-based solution for the artists in the future."? Thanks

Comment: @danicotra Canonical [announced](https://insights.ubuntu.com/2017/04/05/growing-ubuntu-for-cloud-and-iot-rather-than-phone-and-convergence/) that they decided to close development of Ubuntu phone and Unity and also delegate the desktop development to [Ubuntu Gnome team](https://ubuntugnome.org/ubuntu-gnome-17-04-released/) so that Canonical could primarily focus on IoT and server-side solutions. This can possibly lead in stagnation of Ubuntu as a desktop for an average user, at least the road is going to be bumpy for a while, as they will contribute significantly less.